# How to get "different" terms in difflib.ndiff?

Tags: python, difflib

I'm trying to do a text comparison via the 'difflib' library.

I was wondering how to JUST get the terms which are specific to the first string sequence vs the second.

Ex:

```
import difflib

one = "If rents are received later than five (5)"
two = "If rents are received later than eight (8)"

n_one = one.replace(" ","\n")
n_two = two.replace(" ","\n")

diff = difflib.ndiff(n_one.splitlines(1),n_two.splitlines(1))

print ''.join(diff)"
# ...
# - five
# - (5) + eight
# + 8
```

I was wondering how to get two strings:

-> Difference in first string:

```
['five','(5)']
```

--> Difference in second string:

```
['eight','(8)']
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
    import difflib

    one = "If rents are received later than five (5)"
    two = "If rents are received later than eight (8)"

    n_one = one.replace(" ","\n")
    n_two = two.replace(" ","\n")

    diff = difflib.ndiff(n_one.splitlines(0),n_two.splitlines(0))

    one_lst = []
    two_lst = []

    for change in diff:
        if change[0] == "-":
            one_lst.append(change[2:])
        elif change[0] == "+":
            two_lst.append(change[2:])

    >>>> one_lst
    ['five', '(5)']
    >>>> two_lst
    ['eight', '(8)']
```

Comment: Thank so much for the reply! It works perfectly.

I was wondering: 
what does the change[2:] code does?

Comment: @swamz `change` is a string variable of the format "[ +-] <something>" so `change[0]` checks for `+` or `-` and `change[2:]` slices the string from the actual change until the end. have a look [here](https://www.pythoncentral.io/cutting-and-slicing-strings-in-python/)

Answer (score 0):

As a one-liner, not using difflib:

```
>>> first, second = zip(*[(a, b) for a, b in zip(one.split(" "), two.split(" ")) if a != b])
>>> first
('five', '(5)')
>>> second
('eight', '(8)')
```

---

This, of course, works because we're dealing here with single string inputs, and the strings differ at exactly the same spot. If the second string ended with `"eight(8)"` instead, this would miss the `'(5)'` in the diff.